# Exporting DataFrame to pptx using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to move my DataFrame I import from excel and put it on my pptx presentation slide. So far came up with following code but have hard time figuring out how to actually move the data frame I already imported to my presentation slide.

```
from pptx import Presentation
import pandas as pd


pr1 = Presentation()

slide1_reg = pr1.slide_layouts[5]

slide1 = pr1.slides.add_slide(slide1_reg)

title1 = slide1.shapes.title
title1.text = "slide 1"

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

print(df) #prints table from excel i need to put into the presentation

pr1.save("new.pptx")
```

Is there any way to move this data frame as a table to power point? Thank you for help.

```
 X1  X2
0   1   4
1   2   3
```

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried and explain why it doesn't work? Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I tried to pick the values using this:
xaw = df.iloc[0, 0]
xag = df.iloc[1, 0]

Comment: maybe you have to get from DataFrame every value separatelly and put it in presentation. OR maybe you should format DataFrame to some string or HTML and then put it presentation. For string you would have to use standard python function OR try [df.to_string()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html). For HTML you could try [df.to_html(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `add_table()` function:
(see [docs](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/table.html))

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hi': [1, 2, 3], 'there': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(4), Inches(1.5)
shape = slide.shapes.add_table(3, 3, x, y, cx, cy)
table = shape.table
cell = table.cell(1, 2)
cell.text = str(df.iloc[1][2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to put the values from dataframe as a Chart using pandas and pptx:

```
    from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
import pandas as pd

pr1 = Presentation()

slide1_reg = pr1.slide_layouts[5]

slide1 = pr1.slides.add_slide(slide1_reg)

title1 = slide1.shapes.title
title1.text = "slide 1"

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

print(df) 

chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = df.iat[0,0], df.iat[1,0] #gets string categories
chart_data.add_series('YTD', (df.iat[0,1], df.iat[1,1])) #gets integer values

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(2), Inches(2.5)
slide1.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)

pr1.save("new2.pptx")
```

My new dataframe from excel looks like this:

```
 Unnamed: 0  a  b  c
0    dataset  4  4  4
1   dataset1  3  3  3
2         aa  2  2  2
```

As a result I get a chart with [dataset, dataset1] categories and series values [4, 3].

Let's imagine I have 20 categories dataset,dataset1...dataset19 and in next column I have integer values. I want to have a chart exported to pptx, do I need to use df.iat[row, column] 20 times for categories and 20 times for series to create a chart? Can I loop it somehow?

Comment: I tried to get the categories and series using:

chart_data.categories = df.iat[0:2,0]  #get data from rows 0,1,2 & column 0 (dataset, dataset1, aa)
chart_data.add_series('YTD', (df.iat[0:2,1])) #get data from rows 0,1,2 & column 1 (4, 3, 2)

It did not work. Error I get is:ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers

I tried lame solution int(df.iat[0:2,0]) but it did not work either.